# Как программно добавить иконку на видеоминиатюру?

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Меня уже давно тревожит одна проблема: при просмотре сериалов я никак не могу запомнить номер последнего эпизода, каждый раз приходится заново искать следующую серию. Я понимаю, что можно было бы просто записывать куда-нибудь номер эпизода, но делать это очень не хочется, потому что лень. Так вот, мне пришла в голову одна идея: "А что, если на просмотренный эпизод будет вешаться соответствующая иконка". Вот как это возможно будет выглядеть: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7359/11027946053_290ee66de5_o.jpg

Зеленая иконка - эпизод просмотрен, оранжевая - начат, но не закончен, если иконки нет, то серию еще не трогали.
Итак, меня интересует вообще возможно ли программно с помощью c# добавлять к миниатюре иконку, и если да то как? Спасибо

Comment: Объясните, чего именно вы хотите. Изменить иконку, как она отображается в Explorer'е? Вы не можете просто так поменять иконку для видеофайла, она внутри него _не содержится_ и определяется расширением. Однако, вы можете сделать это при помощи WinAPI:

* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775227.aspx
* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
* http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects
* http://stackoverflow.com/a/5817495/276994

Comment: откройте для себя xbmc